# What is the accessible in the class org.demo.mypackage1.C by their short names without writing any imports?

Tags: java

You have the following classes:

```
  org.demo.A
  org.demo.B
  org.demo.mypackage1.C
  org.demo.mypackage2.D
```

Select all classes that are accessible in the class org.demo.mypackage1.C by their short names without writing any imports.

Select one or more options from the list

```
  org.demo.mypackage1.C
  java.lang.String
  org.demo.B
  org.demo.mypackage2.D
  java.util.Scanner
  org.demo.A
```

No matter what I choose, it shows that it is not correct :-(
Please help!
[image]

Comment: This sounds like a quiz question.  Give your answers (with justifications) and I will tell you if you are correct.

Comment: Check your packages again, you are making a mistake (hint: `org.demo.A` is the class A in package org.demo, you have `org.demo.A.A`)

Comment: - org.demo.A
 - org.demo.B
 - org.demo.mypackage2.D
The first three responses that can be called, since the full batch address is specified there

 - org.demo.mypackage1.C
we are already in this package and can directly access "C"

java.util.Scanner
 - We need it if we used the scanner

 - java.lang.String
Not necessary

Comment: @Fullslack: according to the task, i created the classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have misunderstood the question that you were asked in the quiz

You first answer (from your comment above) is

> - `org.demo.A`
> - `org.demo.B`
> - `org.demo.mypackage2.D` The first three responses that can be called, since the full batch address is specified there

In fact, they can't.  The quiz question is:

> *Select all classes that are accessible in the class org.demo.mypackage1.C **by their short names** [and] **without writing any imports**.*

(Emphasis added.)

But you say "since the full batch address is specified there".  In fact, it isn't "specified there" since you are not allowed to `import` it.

Since neither `A`, `B` or `D` is declared in `C`'s package (i.e. in `org.demo.mypackage1`), they **cannot** be referred to in `C` by their short name.

---

> - `org.demo.mypackage1.C` we are already in this package and can directly access `C`

That is correct.

---

> `java.util.Scanner` - We need it if we used the scanner

The answer is that `Scanner` **cannot** be referenced in `C` by its short name without an `import`.

---

> - `java.lang.String` Not necessary

The answer is that `String` **can** be referenced in `C` by its short name without an `import`.  Classes and interfaces in `java.lang` are implicitly imported<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1 - It is more complicated if you declare a top level or inner class or interface with the same name as one in `java.lang`; e.g. `String`.  Then your `String` class declaration will hide the `String` declaration in `java.lang` ... which can be very confusing.</sup>